# Sharepoint - create blank page with only webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

A client has asked that I create a series of filters on a list, with some heavily customised output. To get the output correct I'll need to style a content query webpart using XSL - which is fine, that's pretty simple.

However, my main problem is how to apply multiple filters to the webpart. I don't know how to have one webpart insert parameters into a content query webpart, so my solution was to use Ajax to load seperate pages (containing webparts) into the page.

So... unless this is all crazy and a bad idea, how can I create a .asp page which has absolutely NOTHING except a single webpart which I can preconfigure and then hard code into the .asp page?

I'm not a .asp man, in fact I'm only really doing this as a favour, so please don't respond saying that I need to do xyz in SharePoint Designer (to which I don't have access) or build a custom module from scratch. :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are specific about not wanting a SharePoint Designer solution, I will give you one using 'Tommy'

In 'Tommy':
File => New => ASPX Page
Insert => SharePoint Controls => WebPartZone

Go in the browser, http://server/mycustompage.aspx
Edit, insert your WebPart.

'Tommy' is a free download, by the way, [get it here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=BAA3AD86-BFC1-4BD4-9812-D9E710D44F42&displaylang=en).

Comment: Hiya, 

hehe thanks, the main problem is that we literally don't have access to SharePoint designer - the client network administrators won't allow us to use it. So unless I can hard code it by hand, SP Designer is useless :(

Comment: And by "let us use it" I mean the copies of "Tommy" we all have installed are unable to connect to the SharePoint site in question - so it can't communicate and set all the site variables/properties.

Comment: A no-so-elegant option is to create a WebPart Page (View All Content Site => Create => WebPart Page) and add a Content Editor WebPart with the CSS to hide everything else in the page:
<style> .ms-nav, .ms-globaltitlearea, .ms-globalleft, .ms-globalright, .ms-titlearealeft, .ms-titlearearight, .ms-globalbreadcrumb, .ms-titleareaframe, .ms-pagetitleareaframe, .ms-bannerContainer, .ms-leftareacell, .ms-rightareacell, .ms-pagebottommarginleft, .ms-pagebottommargin, .ms-pagebottommarginright, .ms-bodyareapagemargin { display: none } </style>

Comment: That would work, you're right, but i think I need a proper solution. I'll just have to ask the client's IT team to provide the aspx page I need.